# Error "No Authorized Function Named Rollup Having Compatible Arguments was Found"

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have sql query in ibm db2 :

```
select p2.payment_type, sum(amount)
rom payments p2 
group by rollup(p2.payment_type);
```

And receives an error:

> NO AUTHORIZED FUNCTION NAMED ROLLUP HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS
>   FOUND

why?

thank

Comment: In order to answer "Why?", we have to see the definition for the rollup() parameter list along with the data definition of `p2.payment_type`. If we can't see the definitions, we can't explain the problem any better than what that error message already is telling you.

Comment: Probably because in your version of DB2 rollup grouping expressions are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there actually exists a function called `rollup` that takes an argument of the same type as `p2.payment_type` that you're authorized to use. If so, see [IBM's Knowledge Center](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00440n.html) more more detailed troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

What platform and version of DB2?

Are you sure it supports `GROUP BY ROLLUP`?

DB2 for IBM i, for instance, didn't add support of rollup until v6.1; which was released in March 2008.